# Android SMS-App shows wrong sender

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sms, nexus-5

On my android 5.0 phone (nexus 5), the sms app shows sms from some (but not all) senders within a wrong conversation view. The sender's numer is +49171xyz, which is also shown in the details view if I long tap on a message. In the header of the conversation, the number shown is 09171xyz (android just bites the "+9" off and adds a "0").

Using the direct answer field in the bottom will send the message to the wrong number.

I checked the contact and did not find anything special, nor the number is longer than others.

Is there a solution for that problem?